# Variable History_Retention_Period for SQL Server System Versioned Tables

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables, sql-server-data-project

I want to be able to setup different retention periods for different environments without having a separate script for each environment. I am currently using the SQL Server Database project in Visual Studio and creating a post deployment script to handle this.

I've setup a Sql cmd variable that gets passed based on the publish profile that I am using that pass in a variable called RetentionPolicyMonths:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <SqlCmdVariable Include="RetentionPolicyMonths">
      <Value>36</Value>
    </SqlCmdVariable>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I would then like to use that in my post deployment script to set the retention policy per table:

```
DECLARE @RetentionPolicyMonths int = CAST('$(RetentionPolicyMonths)' AS int)

ALTER TABLE [benefits].[Address] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (History_Retention_Period = @RetentionPolicyMonths MONTHS));
```

My issue here is that it will not currently let me set the History_Retentin_Period property using a variable the way I am doing it now. This is the error that I am currently seeing:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '@RetentionPolicyMonths'.Expecting -, ID, INT, or NUMERIC
```

Can I set this using a variable, or can I only supply the number?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for that `ALTER TABLE` option is as follows

```
[, HISTORY_RETENTION_PERIOD =
                          {
                              INFINITE | number {DAY | DAYS | WEEK | WEEKS
                  | MONTH | MONTHS | YEAR | YEARS }
                          }
                          ]
```

So it looks like you cannot use a variable in that statement.

You can still pass a parameter in, if you use dynamic SQL

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
ALTER TABLE [benefits].[Address] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (History_Retention_Period = ' + CAST(@RetentionPolicyMonths AS varchar(10)) + ' MONTHS));
';

EXEC (@sql);
```

But you appear to actually be interpolating the value into the query anyway (this is *not* the same as passing a parameter), so you may as well just interpolate that directly, so long as you are *sure* of its veracity.

```
ALTER TABLE [benefits].[Address] SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (History_Retention_Period = '$(RetentionPolicyMonths)' MONTHS));
```